# i cant get the correct height() and get width()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, height, width

I have a function that is called when a button is clicked.

The function first changes the size of the control and then i have 2 lines of code that fetch the height and width of a control and display them in the paragraph as text.

When the user first clicks on the button they will get the wrong values of 340*150 and when they click the button again they get the correct values 600*400

the 340*150 is the old/original size before the control expands.

However on the first click even though the wrong values are displayed i still get the correct control size of 600*400 displaying.

```
function a () {
 //change control to 600*400
 //now get the height and width and display in 'p' and 'g'.
 document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = jQuery("#hi").width();
 document.getElementById('g').innerHTML = jQuery("#hi").height();
}

<button id="btn" onClick="a()"> Maximize 600x400 </button
```

also using settimeout function resolves the issue. but i want to fix it properly.

Comment: Can you provide the html and javascript you have so far?  Or at least a condensed operable version?

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply. I had the js code. I have updated the code to include html too.

Comment: can you put the code for setting the width and height of "#hi", if you set them with `jQuery("#hi").width(600)` it should be fine.

Comment: I think this happens because the browser needs a little bit of time to actually change the DOM. and you check the width and height too quickly afterwards. That's why setTimeout fixes the issue. It makes it wait a couple ms for the DOM to update. I think the only other "proper" way might be to set some kind of event listener on the element resize. Not really sure if that's possible though.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this?

```
function a () {
  var w = 600;
  var h = 400;
  // change control to 600*400 using the w and h variables
  // code to do that here ...      

  // now get the height and width and display in 'p' and 'g'.
  document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = w;
  document.getElementById('g').innerHTML = h;
}

<button id="btn" onClick="a()"> Maximize 600x400 </button
```

If the size of your element is properly being changed then the numbers should be the same either way. No need to get the numbers from the element.

Comment: This code wouldn't change the "#hi" element size at all.

Comment: @AliTahouri - I know, I was just taking the example given and adding the variables. It's implied that the person already knows how to change the size. I didn't add that code because I wasn't sure by what methods they were using the change the size.

Comment: @AliTahouri - I realize that wasn't totally clear though from my answer. I edited my code to be more clear on that.

Comment: Right, that's ok then. however my biggest concern is about the way she tries to resize the element, I think the issue raise from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an event on page load, say `btnResize`, then you can emit it after the resize, it will solve your problem.  jQuery uses `trigger()` to emit an event.

```js
function a(){
  $('#hi').width(600);
  $('#hi').height(400);
  $('#hi').trigger('btnResize');
}

$('#hi').on('btnResize', function(){
  $('#p').html($('#hi').width());
  $('#g').html($('#hi').height());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="btn" onClick="a()"> Maximize 600x400 </button>
<div id="p"></div>
<div id="g"></div>
<br>
<button id="hi" style="width:340px; height:150px;" > resize me </button>
```

I believe your issue was as simple as the asynchronous nature of JavaScript.  You were getting the width and height before the function `a()` was called.